# I keep getting an error of a blank excel opening,no file opens

Tags: c#, excel

```
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
MessageBox.Show("The excel file about to open");
Excel.ApplicationClass oExcel = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
oExcel.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbooks oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks;
Excel._Workbook oBook = null;
MessageBox.Show("opening excel sheet");
oBook = oBooks.Open(fileName, oMissing, oMissing,oMissing,oMissing,oMissing,oMissing, oMissing, oMissing,                oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
MessageBox.Show("THE FILE IS OPEN");

MessageBox.Show("Macro about to be run");
RunMacro(oExcel, new Object[] { "Macro1" });

MessageBox.Show("the macro is completed");
oBook.Close(false, oMissing, oMissing); 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBook);
oBook = null;             
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBooks);
oBooks = null;
oExcel.Quit();   
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExcel);
oExcel = null;
```

This code opens a blank excel window instead of the file being open.
Macro has also being defined.

Comment: You could avoid all those `oMissing` parameters if you used the `dynamic` type. It was added to make interop easier among other things.

Comment: i did try removing those, still the same error appears.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the example in
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3k79a5x.aspx

Replace

```
oBook = oBooks.Open(fileName, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, ...
```

With

```
oBook = oBooks.Open(fileName);
```

Also, I would make sure that fileName has the full path to the workbook you're trying to open

Comment: Have you debugged and verified that you have the full path to the file name?
If you set a breakpoint at that line you should be able to copy the value of "fileName", hit windows + R and paste your value. Run. Does that open your desired workbook?